# Webview database corruption on Android

Tags: android, database, exception, webview

I'm developing an Android app which uses a webview to display a webpage. Most of my code is related to the webview. My main activity contains a webview which displays an specific web site.

I'm trying to prevent an error when my webview.db is corrupted. I know that is not a common situation but I would like to make sure that my app will not crash.

Attempting to access the webview database when it has been
corrupted will result in a crash.

I added the method setUncaughtExceptionHandler to handle the exception. I can catch the exeption but when I tried to restart my app the webview never finishes loading.

I tried the follow code to "restart" my app:

```
     Intent i = new Intent(context, Error.class);
                 i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                 i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                 context.startActivity(i);
```

My last try was unsuccessfully then I added some code which displays an error message,  removes the webview databases and closes the app.

```
    AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                    DiscoverMobile.this).create();
            alertDialog.setTitle("Error");
            alertDialog.setMessage("Application files have been deleted or corrupted.  The app will close to fix this issue.  You can restart the app later");
            alertDialog.setButton("OK",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                int which) {


                            webview.getContext().deleteDatabase(
                                    "webview.db");
                            webview.getContext().deleteDatabase(
                                    "webviewCache.db");
                            WebViewDatabase webViewDB = WebViewDatabase
                                    .getInstance(getBaseContext());

                            System.exit(0);
                        }
                    });
            alertDialog.show();
```

Could this be a good solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Override
public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
    super.onPageFinished(view, url);
    view.clearCache(true);
}
```

Maybe you tried this, but maybe also set the WebView Cache size to something small. I'm not sure if 0 will work, so maybe 1:

```
webview.getSettings().setAppCacheMaxSize(1);
```